# Оптимизировать код sql

Tags: sql, циклы, while

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]Есть таблица в которую каждые полчаса с весов поступают данные о массе руды. Необходимо сделать выборку суммы всей руды за каждый день за месяц. Осложняется все тем что день считается сменой - т.е начало смены это 20.00 предыдущего дня и конец смены это 19.50 сегодняшнего дня.
вот код с циклом :

```
declare @d int, @dd float, @s datetime, @e datetime, @s1 datetime, @e1 datetime, @i int, @date1 DATETIME,@d1 float, @d2 float,@d3 float, @d4 float,@d5 float,@d6 float,@d7 float,@d8 float,@d9 float,@d10 float,@d11 float,@d12 float,@d13 float,@d14 float,@d15 float,@d16 float,@d17 float, @d21 float,@d22 float,@d23 float,@d24 float,@d25 float,@d26 float,@d27 float,@d18 float,@d19 float,@d20 float, @d28 float,@d29 float,@d30 float,@d31 float; 

select @d=DATEPART (day,GETDATE()), 
@i=1, @date1= EOMONTH(DATEADD(month,-1,getdate())) 
SELECT @d1=sum([Value]) FROM [172.20.0.12].[ProSoft].[dbo].[Mains] WHERE (ID_Channel=1687) and MeasureDate between DATEADD(hour,20,@date1) and DATETimeFROMPARTS (DATEPART (year,GETDATE()), DATEPART (MONTH,(GETDATE())),1,19,50,00,00) 

while @i < @d 
begin 
select 
@e=DATETimeFROMPARTS (DATEPART (year,GETDATE()), DATEPART (MONTH,GETDATE()),DATEPART (day,@i),19,50,00,00), 
@s=DATETimeFROMPARTS (DATEPART (year,GETDATE()), DATEPART (MONTH,GETDATE()),DATEPART (day,(@i-1)),20,00,00,00) 
SELECT @dd =sum([Value]) 
FROM [172.20.0.12].[ProSoft].[dbo].[Mains] 
WHERE (ID_Channel=1687) and MeasureDate between @s and @e 
GROUP BY DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(mm, 0, MeasureDate), 0) 
set @i=@i+1 
if @i =2 select @d2=round((@dd/1000),1) 
if @i =3 select @d3=round((@dd/1000),1) 
if @i =4 select @d4=round((@dd/1000),1) 
if @i =5 select @d5=round((@dd/1000),1) 
if @i =6 select @d6=round((@dd/1000),1) 
if @i =7 select @d7=round((@dd/1000),1) 
if @i =8 select @d8=round((@dd/1000),1) 
if @i =9 select @d9=round((@dd/1000),1) 
if @i =10 select @d10=round((@dd/1000),1) 
if @i =11 select @d11=round((@dd/1000),1) 
if @i =12 select @d12=round((@dd/1000),1) 
if @i =13 select @d13=round((@dd/1000),1) 
if @i =14 select @d14=round((@dd/1000),1) 
if @i =15 select @d15=round((@dd/1000),1) 
if @i =16 select @d16=round((@dd/1000),1) 
if @i =17 select @d17=round((@dd/1000),1)
 if @i =18 select @d18=round((@dd/1000),1)
if @i =19 select @d19=round((@dd/1000),1) 
if @i =20 select @d20=round((@dd/1000),1) 
if @i =21 select @d21=round((@dd/1000),1) 
if @i =22 select @d22=round((@dd/1000),1) 
if @i =23 select @d23=round((@dd/1000),1)
 if @i =24 select @d24=round((@dd/1000),1) 
if @i =25 select @d25=round((@dd/1000),1) 
if @i =26 select @d26=round((@dd/1000),1) 
if @i =27 select @d27=round((@dd/1000),1) 
if @i =28 select @d28=round((@dd/1000),1) 
if @i =29 select @d29=round((@dd/1000),1) 
if @i =30 select @d30=round((@dd/1000),1) 
if @i =31 select @d31=round((@dd/1000),1) 

end 
select round((@d1/1000),1) as '1',@d2 as '2', @d3 as '3', @d4 as '4', @d5 as '5',@d6 as '6', @d7 as '7' ,@d8 as '8', @d9 as '9',@d10 as '10', @d11 as '11', @d12 as '12', @d13 as '13', @d14 as '14', @d15 as '15',@d16 as '16', @d17 as '17', @d18 as '18', @d19 as '19', @d20 as '20', @d21 as '21', @d22 as '22', @d23 as '23', @d24 as '24', @d25 as '25',@d26 as '26', @d27 as '27', @d28 as '28', @d29 as '29', @d30 as '30', @d31 as '31'
```

---

Можно ли как то его оптимизировать, может еще одним циклом сделать вывод суммы за день?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Вообще-то SQL Server знает про [PIVOT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/from-using-pivot-and-unpivot?view=sql-server-ver16).. а миллион переменных - это вообще за гранью.

Comment: оптимизировать можно только по определенному параметру(по времени исполнения, по занимаемой памяти, по весу исходного кода). Вы по какому хотите?

Comment: *Осложняется все тем что день считается сменой - т.е начало смены это 20.00 предыдущего дня и конец смены это 19.50* Нет тут никакой сложности. Если не получается - ну попробуй к дате-времени отсчёта прибавить 4 часа..

Comment: Оптимизировать - сократить код., убрать переменные. Скрипт рабочий но без миллиона переменных из цикла выводится значения за каждый день в виде отдельных таблиц. Это не подходит для меня, т.к. далее данные выводятся в скаду.

Comment: Добавлена картинка, вывод без переменных

Comment: @Margo То есть вы хотите оптимизировать по объему исходного кода?

Comment: Меня интересует как можно вытащить данные из цикла без ввода доп. переменных. Подскажите пожалуйста